# ESP32 serial connection to raspberry pi is "laggy"

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port, esp32

I am using a ESP32 to write data to other devices. This works quite well, but when I send data to a Raspi I get a strange delay and wrong chars. Sometime the Pi seems to receive the correct data buts its totally random and takes forever.

Sending (ESP32):

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define RXD2 16
#define TXD2 17

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Initialize");
  Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
}

void loop() {
  Serial2.println("Sending data to you!");
  Serial.println("Data send.");
  delay(222);
}
```

Received data on Pi via `sudo screen /dev/ttyS0 9600`:

[image]

Comment: BTW. I tried diffrent cables, baud, delays etc. Sending from ESP32 to FTDI USB PC works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I did used a 5V 1A power supply for the RPi, which supplied not enough power. I am using a 3A now which runs perfecly flawless.

Comment: I love it when mysteries like this are solved, and posted. I wouldn't have thought of the power supply until way later.

Comment: @Bucky Thanks! I promise I did a lot of research and was nearly at the point to use a spectrum analyzer to see if there are timing issues, which would be very strange because its not a hardcore mikrocontroller communication on the edge (9600 BAUD woooooo). I really didn't expect power, because all other functions worked well while communicating.

Answer (score 0):

connect Arduino to the usb of the raspberry pi and try sudo screen dev/ubs(in which the arduino is connected) 9600 or try installing minicom and use "minicom -D /dev/ttyso -b 9600".

Comment: Thank you Binjaw, I answered my question by myself in answer 1.  It was the power supply.